# Flutter : Border color on Alertdialog and font

Tags: flutter, colors, android-alertdialog, border

I'm new to flutter and i'm trying to put a border color to an AlertDialog.
I can't find a way to do it, so i tried to replace it with a container but the font isn't the same and i can't find the correct font.
Here is the AlertDialog i'm trying to replicate.
The font is the same used for the FlatButton label, yet i still can't find it.

```
AlertDialog(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          title:Center(child:Text(contact.name + " "+ contact.familyName)),
          content:Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(_role,style: _style),
              Divider(
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
              ),
              FlatButton.icon(
                label: Text(
                  "Voir le profil",
                ),
                icon:Icon(
                  Icons.account_circle,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                onPressed:(){
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserProfileScreen(userId:contact.id)),
                  );
                },
              ),
              FlatButton.icon(
                label: Text(
                  "Ajouter en ami",
                  style:TextStyle(color:Colors.green),
                ),
                icon:Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),

                onPressed:()=>Navigator.pop(context,RoleActions.AJOUT_AMI),
              ),
              _buildPermissions(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

[image: Correct alert dialog]
[image: Alert dialog replica when using dialog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced everything with a container to mimic an AlertDialog, and copied data from the theme

```
Container(
    padding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 24.0),
    child:Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: lighten(Theme.of(context).primaryColor,10),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
              border: Border.all(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
              ),
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child : Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  contact.name + " "+ contact.familyName,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6.copyWith(color:Colors.red),
                ),
                Text(_role,style: _style,textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                Divider(
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                ),
                FlatButton.icon(
                  label: Text(
                    "Voir le profil",
                  ),
                  icon:Icon(
                    Icons.account_circle,
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                  ),
                  onPressed:(){
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserProfileScreen(userId:contact.id)),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                FlatButton.icon(
                  label: Text(
                    "Ajouter en ami",
                    style:TextStyle(color:Colors.green),
                  ),
                  icon:Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),

                  onPressed:()=>Navigator.pop(context,RoleActions.AJOUT_AMI),
                ),
                _buildPermissions(),
              ],
            ),
          )
)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're just looking for a border, you can set that with `shape`:

```dart
return AlertDialog(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont replace the whole thing with the container rather than enclose them with a container.
like this

```
Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.white  //Add color of your choice
                  )
                ),
                child: AlertDialog()),
```

Comment: Hello, AlertDialogs are inherited from Dialog and have built-in padding, so enclosing it in a container would create a border, then a blank padding then the alert dialog. I replaced everything with a container since i couldn't get a good result. Still, thanks a lot for answering :)